# Background color of Button in TableLayout

Tags: android

I'm having trouble figuring out why this behaves as it does:

```
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        table.addView(row);
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            FrameLayout cell = new FrameLayout(this);
            cell.setBackgroundColor((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.YELLOW : Color.WHITE);
            Button b = new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
            b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10);
            b.setText("B-\n" + Integer.toString(counter++));
            b.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            b.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(120, 120, 0x11));
                // 0x11 = center
            if (i == 3 && j == 3)
                b.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(0xcc0088));
            cell.addView(b);
            row.addView(cell);
            cell.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1F));
        }
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1F));
    }
```

I'm using `nrows==10`, `ncols==5`.  This displays a checkerboard pattern of white and yellow "squares", and in the center of each square other than (3,3) is a gray button with some text in it.  In the (3,3) square, though, where I used `setBackground` with a `ColorDrawable` with a sort of magenta color, only the text appears; the square is entirely yellow except for the text.  There's no gray button, but the magenta color I tried to apply to the button doesn't show up anywhere either.  (Using `b.setBackgroundColor(0xcc0088)` has the same result.)

Is there an explanation for what's going on?  Am I missing something obvious, or does `setBackground` behave differently for a button inside a `TableLayout`, or what?  How can I set the color of the button programmatically, without changing the color of the enclosing square?

Comment: (0xcc0088) has alpha of 0, is it what you want? i dont think so

Comment: @pskink Duhhhhhhhhhhhhhh...  Thanks.  I was hoping it was something simple.